# How can I modify a variable in one file and use it in another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to:

- Declare a variable in one file
- Write its value in a second file
- Read its value in a third file

Here is my minimum example:

File "modify.py":

```
from declare import *
from use import *

array = [[0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]
print("array:")
for row in array:
    print(row)

i_hate_python()
i_really_hate_python()
```

File "declare.py":

```
array = [[]]

def i_hate_python():
    print("array:")
    for row in array:
        print(row)
```

File "use.py":

```
from declare import *

def i_really_hate_python():
    print("array:")
    for row in array:
        print(row)
```

I am running the problem like so:

```
python modify.py
```

The output is:

```
array:
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
array:
[]
array:
[]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
array:
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
array:
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
array:
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

Thanks in advance for not leaving any comments about how I must be designing my program badly.

Comment: Nothing is causing modify.py to be loaded.   Try importing it explicitly.

Comment: I'm running modify.py. Edited the question to include this.

Comment: don't use global variables, it will bite you later, pass them as function arguments

Comment: @rioV8 did you not read the line that says "Thanks in advance for not leaving any comments about how I must be designing my program badly."

Comment: I don't completely understand what's going on.  But if you change `array = ....` in modify.py to `array.append(.....)`, it does the right thing.  Apparently you are creating a second variable `array` in modify.py when you do the assignment.  

I suppose this makes sense.  I shouldn't be able to do 'from math import *; sin = cos` and mess up every other use of sin in my program.  

In any case, most of us don't completely understand the semantics of importing globals and then assigning them.  Just because it's not something we do.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that does seem to work. I can use this solution if necessary. If you want to post a response, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]
```

That line of code in modify.py recreates `array` as a local variable, and you've lost the imported variable of the same name.

Try this instead:

```
import declare
declare.array = ...
```

By prefixing `declare.` to the variable name, you keep the association with its containing module.

Comment: When I switch the imports as you say, now the function i_hate_python() is no longer defined in modify.py (specifically, the problem is switching 'from use import *' to 'import use').

Comment: I edited the question to include a function in declare.py to illustrate the problem a little better.